# Where to put SQLite database in UWP app

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

Current [Entity Framework Core Documentation](https://readthedocs.com/projects/aspnet-ef/downloads/pdf/latest/) gives an example for using SQLite in a Windows 10 / UWP app. The example given declares the db location with  `optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=Blogging.db");` The path is equivalent to `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` This puts the SQLite database in `<packagefolder>\LocalState`.

We are exploring using UWP/SQLite for a business application which stores business transactions in a SQLite db. However the folder name `LocalState` suggests to me this is the place to store state information, not long term storage of business transactions.

There is another folder `<packagefolder>\AppData`. Is this a more appropriate location for our db? If so, how is it accessed in a UWP app? Or is `<packagefolder>\LocalState` after all the correct place to put a db that is used for long term storage of business transactions?

Answer (score 5):

Documentation is right. The path for the database (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path) is correct. Your data will exist as long as the app is installed on the device.

Please see below MSDN article and what is the most important from it:

"local data, which exists as long as the app that created it remains installed"

And one more:

"Local can contain both files (LocalFolder) and settings (LocalSettings) and should be used for any information that is of user value and can’t easily be recreated or downloaded"

ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder is used to store the information.

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/10/getting-started-storing-app-data-locally/#_Local

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Krzyczkowski. I had marked this correct, but the link you referred to doesn't mention LocalState. It is the fact that the db ends up in LocalState that has me concerned. Also there is no mention of the AppData folder which is a sibling of LocalState.

Comment: @Vague "ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder" refers to "%AppData%/Local/Packages/<yourapppackage>/LocalState" in file system. That is why you see database in "<packagefolder>\LocalState". AppData is the folder inside which you can find app packages (so higher in the hierarchy)

Comment: Not on my Windows 10 machine @Daniel Krzyczkowski. Inside the package folder I have these folders: AC, AppData, LocalCache, LocalState, RoamingState, Settings, SystemAppData, TempState

Comment: I wanted to add that I found out while debugging @DanielKrzyczkowski is right. If you break right before you finish an action while debugging go to the path it shows after catching it in a variable. Usually, I end up with it in Local State but in some rare cases it oddly ends up in AppData. The